# How to edit an existing and working Schema in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to continue or extend an existing schema with MySQL Workbench?
This is the scenery:
1) We design our DB in MySQL Workbench
2) We export it as SQL file and execute it in our MySQL Server
3) We insert a lot of data and use our DB
4) We want to add more tables, fields, or anything to our Schema

The 4 step is my dude, can we edit our scheme in MySQL Workbench if our DB is working and with data?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use file->import and select an sql file, which you can export via phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Yes but I need to "continue" or update the design, not to create again all the scheme, just the new tables and relations.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can sync your database with workbench model. the sync works both ways so you can update the model from the database, or update the database from the model.